# Can I typecast a Base to Derived interface type?

Tags: delphi, soap, interface

Can i typecast a base interface to derived interface.

How do I make like Delphi

Delphi generated code / Delphi 7 :

```delphi
function TXMLBook.Get_Id: IXMLId;
begin
   Result := ChildNodes['id'] as IXMLId;
end;
```

ChildNodes['id'] is base type IXMLNode

IXMLId is derived type from IXMLNode

and my sample code is  :

```delphi
type
IBase = interface(IInterface)
['{5CEA3668-36CB-444C-8D3E-06644070A2B4}']
  function Test:AnsiString;
end;

TBase =class(TInterfacedObject,IBase)
  function Test:AnsiString;
end;

IDerived =interface (IBase)
['{8CDB2982-43B0-4636-B6F5-2561C0D419A9}']
  function Test2: AnsiString;
end;

TDerived=class (TBase,IDerived)
  function Test:AnsiString;
  function Test2:AnsiString;
end;

{ TBase }

function TBase.Test: AnsiString;
begin
   Result:='Base Test';
end;

{ TDerived }

function TDerived.Test: AnsiString;
begin
  Result:='Derived Test';
end;

function TDerived.Test2: AnsiString;
begin
   Result:='Derived Test2';
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  b:IBase;
  d: IDerived;
begin
  b:=TBase.Create;
  d:=b as IDerived; // Error : Interface not supported 

  ShowMessage(b.Test);
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `TBase` class currently does not implement `IDerived`, it only implements `IBase`.
Your `TDerived` class implements both `IBase` *(by inheriting from `TBase`)* and `IDerived` *(explicitly)*.

You should either

1. Change your `TBase` declaration to

   `TBase =class(TInterfacedObject,IBase, IDerived)`

   and implement the `IDerived` methods in `TBase`.
2. or change `b:=TBase.Create;` to `b:=TDerived.Create`;

Comment: Thanks @Lieven. Delphi is how to do this, you know? I do not know the classes will be produced later.

Comment: @zgn - I'm not sure I understand your comment. Is it a question or an observation?

Comment: Actually, I'm trying to similar to Delphi code. What can you say for the topmost delphi sample.

Comment: Delphi uses IXMLNode,IXMLCollectionList base interfaces. But functions can export Different types.  Another example : [link](http://code.marcocantu.com/p/marcodelphibooks/source/tree/9/masteringdelphi7/22/XmlInterface/XmlIntfDefinition.pas) . I want to learn how to do this ?

Comment: I don' see anything special about the link you've provided but you have to keep in mind that interfaces can not really be inherited from like objects can. True, `IDerived` *inherits* the method signatures from `IBase` but that **does not** mean that an object implementing `IDerived` also implicitely implements `IBase`.